# How to register a COM dll which uses MSXML?

Tags: c#, .net, msxml, regasm

I got a COM dll which uses MSXML and it is developed in C#.net and i want to use that in delphi as a type library. when i try to register that DLL using REGASM it is throwing error as below

```
Error: Type library exporter cannot load type 'MSXML.IXMLDOMDocument' (error: System.IO.FileNotFoundExc
eption: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSXML, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture
=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fin
d the file specified.
File name: 'Interop.MSXML, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: Do you know where Interop.MSXML is, whether it needs to be deployed?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio/C# are you using to create the DLL? If possible, its XML type information ought to be [embedded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or, alternatively, why is this .NET DLL using the COM XML component rather than the ones built into .NET?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ..we are not suppose to deploy Interop.MSXML

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever we are using Visual Studio 2010. if .net is returning IXMLDOCUMENT , Delphi is not able to recognize IXMLDOMDOCUMENT format so it is showing as IUNKNOWN. so we planned to use COM XML component.